# Retrofit + RxJava + Unit test

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, rxjava, retrofit2

Есть `unit test` для `Retrofit` запросы щас мне возвращают типизированые ответы от сервера `Call<List<GroupObject>>` в таком виде достаточно просто его тестировать:

```
    GroupObject group = new GroupObject("Test group", "short name", "image/logo/ava.img", GroupCategory.AUTO_MOTO, this.USER_ID);
    String json = this.gson.toJson(group);
    Response<GroupObject> insertResponse = this.groupApi.insertNewGroup(json).execute();
    GroupObject insertedGroup = insertResponse.body();
    assertEquals("Request successful", 200, insertResponse.code());
    assertNotNull("Body is not empty", insertedGroup);
    assertNotNull("Id must not be null", insertedGroup.getId());

    Response<List<GroupObject>> getResponse = this.groupApi.getGroups().execute();
    List<GroupObject> all = getResponse.body();
    assertEquals("Request successful", 200, getResponse.code());
    assertNotNull("Body is not empty", all);
    assertTrue("List of groups must containst minimum one group which was created above",
            all.stream().anyMatch(object -> {
                return object.getId() != null && object.getId().equals(insertedGroup.getId());
            })
    );
```

Но я хочу вместо:

```
Call<List<GroupObject>> getGroups();
```

использовать:

```
Observable<List<GroupObject>> getGroups();
```

Но не могу понять как написать аналогичный тест, но для `Observable`.

Нашел [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39827081/5634351) относящийся к этой теме, но не до конца понимаю  как получить аналогичный тесты при использовании `Observable`.

Дополнительно помимо `JUnit` добавил зависимости `Mockito`.

Подскажите, как можно реализовать аналогичный тест но с использованием `Observable`.

Comment: А зачем вам `Observable`?

Comment: Я хочу использовать его в UI. А что, Вы в том смысле что можно без него обойтись, используя Call?

Comment: @Flippy Вот один из примеров того что я хочу сделать http://www.computools.com/blog/creation-of-the-weather-app-using-mvp-rxjava-and-retrofit-2/

Comment: нет, нет, я просто про него прочитал недавно и не понял зачем он вообще. Можете обьяснить чем `Observable` так хорош? ;)

Comment: Я сам только начал разбитраться, но если коротко то: вместо данных из HTTP запроса я могу получить данные завернутые в Observable и используя метод subscribeы я могу вызвать код отсносящийся к UI  и обновить в нем полученные данные.

Comment: Волшебный `Observable`

Comment: @Flippy ну что то типа того. Хочу щас применить на практике, но не могу начать пока не пойму как их тестировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в тесте логика завязана на обработке объекта `Response`. Адаптер Retrofit2 для RxJava2 может возвращать как `Observable<T>`, так и `Observable<Response<T>>`. Второй случай больше похож на ваш, тогда тип возвращаемого значения из api будет `Observable<Response<List<GroupObject>>>` или `Single<Response<List<GroupObject>>>`, тут уж как удобнее. Для тестирования реактивных источников можно воспользоваться специальным классом `TestObserver`, тогда тест может выглядеть примерно так:

```
    TestObserver<Response<List<GroupObject>>> testObserver = TestObserver.create();

    groupApi.getGroups().subscribe(testObserver);

    testObserver.assertNoErrors();
    testObserver.assertComplete();

    assertTrue(testObserver.valueCount() > 0);

    Response<List<GroupObject>> getResponse = testObserver.values().get(0);
    List<GroupObject> all = getResponse.body();
    assertEquals("Request successful", 200, getResponse.code());
```

PS В своем ответе я помогаю с написанием аналогичного теста, который использует автор, за корректность такого рода тестов я не отвечаю. =)

Comment: Бегло попробовал протестить ваш код, по-моему это то что надо. Спасибо!